# Elasticsearch configuration on google cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I have installed elastic search on google cloud. I get this error when I try to connect to it:

```
Elasticsearch ERROR: 2017-04-17T04:27:45Z
  Error: Request error, retrying
  HEAD http://localhost:9200/ => connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
```

In `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.ym` file, I have unsuccessfully tried :

```
network.host:  127.0.0.1
```

and

```
#network.host: 192.168.0.1 (default)
```

I appreciate if someone help me find out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

on which interface do you want your ElasticSearch to listen to ?

Quickly you can start ES and locally inspect listening sockets with :

- `netstat -tlpn`
- `ss -tlpn`

By default ES listens to localhost, you can find how to manage this here :

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html

Kind regards.